# Display previously selected value in drop down when editing record in mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I have inherited a little php page that allows a user to enter relocation requests and then go back in and edit them.

The add page has a number of drop down boxes, but the edit page just shows them as a text field.  If you need to select a different value in the edit page you need to know all the values from the drop down box.

I am trying to come up with a way to show the previous selected value from the drop down box in a drop down box on the edit page to easily allow someone to change the value if need be.

I have seen some other questions and answers like this using the 'selected' method but I can't relate that to the code I am looking at.  I am not great expert in php and use examples and solutions on here to make things work.  In this instance I just cannot put it together.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

```
<?php
$resultNames = $conn->query("SELECT txtCraftGroup FROM tblCraftGroup Order 
by txtCraftGroup");
if($resultNames) {
?>
<tr>
<td>Craft: </td>
<td><select name="craft">
<option value="0">Please Select</option>
<?php
while ($MCraft = $resultNames->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<option value=\"{$MCraft['txtCraftGroup']}\">";
  echo $MCraft['txtCraftGroup'];
  echo "</option>";
}

}else{
?>
<td>Craft: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="craft" value="<?php echo $MCraft; ?>"/><br/>
</td>
<?php
  }
  ?>
  </select><td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: @Vanitha Kesavan there was no data populated on the edit screen when the dropdown list was populated and the rest of the fields stopped being displayed also.  Not sure where the $craftval came from either.  I know I seem like I am fishing around in the dark with this one.  Just couldn't make the solution work.

Answer (score 1):

```
To display the selected option in dropdown


<td><select name="craft">
<?php
while ($MCraft = $resultNames->fetch_assoc()) 
{  ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $MCraft['txtCraftGroup'] ;?>" 

          <?php if ($MCraft['txtCraftGroup']==$craftval) echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?> >

         <?php echo $MCraft['txtCraftGroup']; ?></option>
  <?php
    } 

?>        

</select> </td>
```

For Example

```
<td><select name="gender">
<?php
while ($row = $resultNames->fetch_assoc()) 
{    ?>

    <option value="male" 
    <?php if ($row['gender']=="male")  echo 'selected = "selected" '; ?> >
      Male
    </option>
    <option value="female" 
                 <?php if ($row['gender']=="female")  echo 'selected = "selected" '; ?> >
    Female
    </option>
    <?php

 } 

?>        
        </select> </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Code:

You can use the selected option.
Suppose if you have two forms:
  Add form.
  Update form.
First post the values in url through the GET method so that you can access the field value in another page.

```
<select name = "field_name">
<option value="<?php echo $_GET["field_name"]; ?>" selected > <?php echo 
$_GET["field_name"]; ?> </option>
{
 //you can add your dropdown condition here if you are fetching an array
}
</select>
```